# jquery on blur but focus on the other one

Tags: jquery, focus, blur

I have a situation that i have a hidden div with two input elements where it hides by default and only shows up if I hover something and disappears back if I hover out.  Now I want that div not to disappear if one of the input element is focused and disappears if blurred.  I have solved that part until, if the focus is transferred from one input to another, the div will disappear which I don't want it to disappear because one of the input is still focused.

Here's my code:

```
// code with the problem I think.
$('#inputText1, #inputText2').live("blur", function() {
    if ($('#myDiv').is(":visible")) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("jqTransformInputWrapper_focus")) {
            $('#myDiv').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    }
});

// hover to show and hide the div
$(".visibleDiv").hover(
    function() {
        $('#myDiv').fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function() {
        if(!$(this).find(".jqTransformInputWrapper").hasClass("jqTransformInputWrapper_focus")) {
            $('#myDiv').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    }
);
```

My Html:

```
<div class="visibleDiv">
    hover me
    <div id="myDiv">
        <input name="inputText1" id="inputText1" type="text" />
        <input name="inputText2" id="inputText2" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

BTW, I'm using jqTransform for the input elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
// code with the problem I think.
$('#inputText1, #inputText2').live("blur", function() {

    if ($('#myDiv').is(":visible")) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("jqTransformInputWrapper_focus")) {
            $('#myDiv').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    }

}).live("focus",function(){
    $('#myDiv').stop(true,true).show();
});
```

Comment: this works great without the `live` but only on FF, is there a work around for this one on IE?

Answer (score 0):

give some class to input box and apply jQuery on that

```
<div class="visibleDiv">
    hover me
    <div id="myDiv">
        <input name="inputText1" id="inputText1" type="text" class="inputbox" />
        <input name="inputText2" id="inputText2" type="text" class="inputbox"/>
    </div>
</div>


// now this will work
$('.inputbox').live("blur", function() {
 // u can also use this
 // if($(this).parent().is(":visible") )
    if ($('#myDiv').is(":visible")) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("jqTransformInputWrapper_focus")) {
            $('#myDiv').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    }
});
```

**Note:** use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of live

Comment: actually that is just the same with what I am doing. Mine is just specific to two.